# Generating a DATASET using OMNet++

Tags: csv, omnet++, inet

After creating a Simulation using OMNet++ and with the help of the INET framework , i have generated `.vec` and `.sca` files , the problem is that when i want to import the `.csv` file i don't get some important features such as the event number , time ...etc., the features that i get are here in this picture :
[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq3QL.png)

So please, what should i do to make these features appear in my output ?

Comment: Please can you clarify what results you want to export from your analysis file. Do you have vectors that you right-click and then export to CSV?

Comment: yes exactly i choose some vectors ( for ex  , the packets sent vector ), than a right click , export to csv file ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be possible to get the event number: https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ana-sim:vector-eventnum-recording but it is not exported by default to CSV

You are already geting the vector time in the value "vectime".

Each vector has a comma separated list of times in vectime and a corresponding comma separated list of values in vecvalue.

Comment: thank you !  i am using the time vector now.

Comment: I have just discovered event numbers are supposedly exported https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ana-sim:vector-eventnum-recording Although I'm afraid I don't know how to view them